# Javascript autocomplete Form and append text in prefilled feild

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a form that will auto complete text fields based on entered first name and last name.  For example:

If the Lastname is : smith
If the Firstname is: John
The email address should be automatically completed as : smithj@abc.com
And the Username should be automatically completed as: smithj.
I have the follow code that completes the username but I can’t figure out how to complete the email part.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="">
<div><label for="lname">Last Name: </label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" /></div>

<div><label for="fname">First Name: </label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="
if(document.form.username.value=='' && document.form.lname.value!='' && document.form.lname.value!='') {
     var username = '';
     if(document.form.fname.value.length >= 4) {
          username = document.form.lname.value.substr(0,49) + document.form.fname.value.substr(0,1);
     } else {
          username = document.form.lname.value.substr(0,49) + document.form.fname.value.substr(0,4);
     }
     username = username.replace(/\s+/g, '');
     username = username.replace(/\'+/g, '');
     username = username.replace(/-+/g, '');
     username = username.toLowerCase();
     document.form.username.value = username; 

     }" /></div>


<div><label for="Email"> Email:      </label><input type="text" name="Email" /></div>
<div><label for="username">Username: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"/></div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your JavaScript code is not really readable, would you mind formatting it a bit better? And for your initial question: you'd just have to append '@abc.com' to the username string: `var email = username + '@abc.com';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make it a complete with an answer ;) Add the following to your script and the email gets filled along with the username, assuming you just want to fill it when username isn't set either:

```
if (document.form.email.value == '') {
    var email = username + '@abc.com';
    document.form.email.value = email;
}
```